# What is causing spurious mouse wheel events using Magic Mouse in applications?

Tags: osx-lion, scrolling, screen-sharing, magic-mouse, chickenvnc

I recently switched to using an Apple Magic Mouse and have found that I am getting spurious mouse wheel events (mouse-5) when moving the mouse intermittently. I've seen this in `Chicken of the VNC`.  With my fingers lightly resting on the mouse edges, sometimes when I move the mouse left to right, intending to move the mouse position to right, instead the window with focus is getting scrolled up and down.

I'm at a loss to figure out why this is occurring and how to configure it to stop.

What is the likely cause of this aberrant behavior that coincides with switching from the track pad of the MacBook Air to an external Magic Mouse on Mac OSX Lion?

The events being generated are of these kind:

```
<mouse-5>
<double-down-mouse-5>
<double-mouse-5>
<triple-down-mouse-5>
<triple-mouse-5>
```